# What is .successor() in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone explain what someVar.successor() is? Apple documentation says "Returns the next consecutive value after `self`.". I don't understand its implementation meaning.

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the docs is this?

Comment: While you are in playground, click on the function name, then select View->Utilities->Show Quick Help Inspector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of adding 1, we can call successor() on index.

For example this :

```
func naturalIndexOfItem(item: Item) -> Int? {
    if let index = indexOfItem(item) {
        return index + 1
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Is equal to this:

```
func naturalIndexOfItem(item: Item) -> Int? {
    if let index = indexOfItem(item) {
        return index.successor()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: But keep in mind that successor() allows overflow. + does not.

Answer (score 9):

The `successor()` method returns the next value after the current one (if any, if the current value is 0 then calling `successor()` will return 1 and so on)

A typical successor() implementation will look like:

```
class ForWardIndexDemo: ForwardIndex
{
    private var _myIndex = 0
    init(index: Int)
    {
       _myIndex = index;
    }

    func successor() -> ForWardIndexDemo
    {
       return ForWardIndexDemo(index:_myIndex++)
    }
}
```

> The collection associated type IndexType specifies which type is used
>   to index the collection. Any type that implements ForwardIndex can be
>   used as the IndexType.
>
> The ForwardIndex is an index that can only be incremented, for example
>   a forward index of value 0 can be incremented to 1,2,3 etc…, This
>   protocol internally inherits from Equatable and _Incrementable
>   protocols. In order to adhere to the ForwardIndex protocol successor()
>   -> Self method and the Equatable protocols must be implemented.

Read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@NSomar/swift-collections-1b271764d79)

Comment: this was similar to the answer I was going to post. :)

Comment: @rakeshbs: Ohh, You can post your answer too. Your answer will also have anything new to learn.

Comment: your answer is better than the accepted one. thats why I commented.

Comment: @rakeshbs: I appreciate your comment. Thanks for the comment :) Happy coding.

Comment: I think your answer is better too :D.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha: Thanks for your comment. May be the OP thinks your answer is very easy to understand :)